# How can I recursively include all files with a specific name in a folder using PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, include

Suppose I have a folder named `parent`
In there, there are many subfolders like `child1`, `child2` etc.
Some of these "child" folders have a file in them called `module.php`.
How can I recursively check all subfolders of the `parent` folder and include all files named `module.php` in my application?

I tried the below and can't figure out what's wrong:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'glob_recursive' ) ) {
  function glob_recursive( $pattern, $flags = 0 ) {
    $files = glob( $pattern, $flags );
    foreach ( glob( dirname( $pattern ) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT ) as $dir ) {
      $files = array_merge( $files, glob_recursive( $dir . '/' . basename( $pattern ), $flags ) );
    }
    return $files;
  }
}

foreach ( glob_recursive( locate_template('/lib/modules/*/module.php' ) as $module ) {
  require_once $module;
}
```

Comment: How about http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php?

Comment: @elclanrs AFAIK `glob` works not recursive

Comment: Oh, you're right, my bad. The iterator should do in the question below.

Comment: I updated my above post to include what I've done, including a glob_recursive function. However it seems like I'm missing something...

Comment: this is the reason I want to get rid of php as soon as I can afford to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it sounds like a bad design to include all files, it is possible:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/');
$recIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$regex = new RegexIterator($recIterator, '/\/module.php$/i');

foreach($regex as $item) {
    include $item->getPathname();
}
```

Btw, this example is derived from a [comment in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228). To make it working, make sure that all sub folders are readable by PHP in that folder. If cannot make this sure you will have to write a custom recursive function for that (but this is unlikely).

Again, what you are doing is not a good design and will lead to problems (earlier than you might think). If you are following the OOP style, a better approach would be to use the [`autload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) mechanism of PHP.

Comment: If you take a look at my original post I updated it to include a sample of what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: But my example should do the trick, isn't it? (have tested it)