# Recursively requiring all files

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to add all files in my project recursively, for this I have used this function:

```
<?php

function RequireFiles()
{
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(abspath . "lib/");
    $recIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

    foreach ($recIterator as $item)
    {
        print $item->getPathname() . "<br />";
        //include $item->getPathname();
    }
}

?>
```

*taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887613/how-can-i-recursively-include-all-files-with-a-specific-name-in-a-folder-using-p) with minor changes*.

My problem is that my output looks like this:

> E:/projects/php/project/project/lib.
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib..
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\class.
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\class..
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\class\Log.php
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\trait.
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\trait..
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\trait\SetLink.php
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\trait\MysqliEsp.php
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\arrays.
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\arrays..
>   E:/projects/php/project/project/lib\arrays\tables.php

I do not want to have the `\.` and `\..` on the end and have looked for an answer for this for a while and cannot find out how to rid myself of these little terrors!

Can someone help me to fix this or point me in the direction of a Q&A that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the flag [`FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants.skip-dots) in the constructor, e.g.

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(abspath . "lib/"
                                            , FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Perfect answer, I'll mark as correct as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

The class **[SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)** (that is what you get from RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator) has a method called `isFile()`.

You can just add `if( !$item->isFile() ) continue;`to your foreach:

```
foreach ( $recIterator as $item ) {
    if( !$item->isFile() ) continue;
    print $item->getPathname() . "<br />";
    //include $item->getPathname();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the name ($key) and discarding what you don't want:

```
foreach ($recIterator as $k=>$item)
{
    if ($k == '.' || $k == '..') { continue; }
    print $item->getPathname() . "<br />";
    //include $item->getPathname();
}
```