# php loop through files in subfolders in folder and get file paths

Tags: php, html

Im really new to PHP i searched google to find a correct script that loops through all subfolders in a folder and get all files path in that subfolder

```
<?php
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('posts');
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    echo $filename. '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

So i have folder 'posts' in which i have subfolder 'post001' in which i have two files

```
controls.png
text.txt
```

And the code above echos this

```
posts\.
posts\..
posts\post001\.
posts\post001\..
posts\post001\controls.png
posts\post001\text.txt
```

But i want to echo only the file paths inside these subfolders like this

```
posts\post001\controls.png
posts\post001\text.txt
```

The whole point of this is that i want to dynamically create divs for each subfolder and inside this div i put img with src and some h3 and p html tags with text equal to the .txt file so is this proper way of doing that and how to remake my php script so that i get just the file paths

So I can see the answers and they are all correct but now my point was that i need something like that

```
foreach( glob( 'posts/*/*' ) as $filePath ){
 //create div with javascript
  foreach( glob( 'posts/$filePath/*' ) as $file ){
      //append img and h3 and p html tags to the div via javascript
  }
  //append the created div somewhere in the html again via javascript
}
```

So whats the correct syntax of doing these two foreach loops in php im really getting the basics now

Comment: This is probably a terrible suggestion but you could just add an `if(strpos($filename, '\.') === false)` before the echo

Comment: by terrible suggestion you mean your suggestion or my idea of doing my task

Comment: I mean there might be a better way to do exactly what you want without wasting CPU checking each result. I've never even seen the functions you use there before, it's just a hacky way to resolve your issue.

Comment: yes your code works thank you but anyways i was thinking of a better foreach function to remove these unwanted folder and subfolder paths

Comment: may be you can use SKIP_DOTS, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132333/recursively-requiring-all-files/34132556#34132556 and php functions like is_dir, http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php to check folders

Comment: I don't know if they are some Windows limitation, but on Unix like this unique command works as you expect: `foreach( glob( 'posts/*/*' ) as $filePath )`

Comment: nice fusion3k make it as answer so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

See if this works :)

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('posts');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {           
    if ((substr($file, -1) != '.') && (substr($file, -2) != '..')) {
        echo $file . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but i thnking of two foreach loops so that before the second loop i can create div (div for each subfolder) and then inside the second loop append html elements insive this div so this recursive function isnt the way i was thinking about

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Directory Listing</h1>
<?php
/**
 * Recursive function to append the full path of all files in a
 * given directory $dirpath to an array $context
 */
function getFilelist($dirpath, &$context){
  $fileArray = scandir($dirpath);
  if (count($fileArray) > 2) {
    /* Remove the . (current directory) and .. (parent directory) */
    array_shift($fileArray);
    array_shift($fileArray);
    foreach ($fileArray as $f) {
      $full_path = $dirpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $f;
      /* If the file is a directory, call the function recursively */
      if (is_dir($full_path)) {
        getFilelist($full_path, $context);
      } else {
        /* else, append the full path of the file to the context array */
        $context[] = $full_path;
      }
    }
  }
}
/* $d is the root directory that you want to list */
$d = '/Users/Shared';
/* Allocate the array to store of file paths of all children */
$result = array();
getFilelist($d, $result);
$display_length = false;
if ($display_length) {
    echo 'length = ' . count($result) . '<br>';
}
function FormatArrayAsUnorderedList($context) {
    $ul = '<ul>';
    foreach ($context as $c) {
      $ul .= '<li>' . $c . '</li>';
    }
    $ul .= '</ul>';
    return $ul;
}
$html_list = FormatArrayAsUnorderedList($result);
echo $html_list;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this:

```
<?php
$filename[] = 'posts\.';
$filename[] = 'posts\..';
$filename[] = 'posts\post001\.';
$filename[] = 'posts\post001\..';
$filename[] = 'posts\post001\controls.png';
$filename[] = 'posts\post001\text.txt';

foreach ($filename as $file) {
    if (substr($file, -4, 1) === ".") {
        echo $file."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Result:

```
posts\post001\controls.png
posts\post001\text.txt
```

What this does is checking if the 4th last digit is a dot. If so, its an extension of three letters and it should be a file. You could also check for specific extensions.

```
$ext = substr($file, -4, 4);
if ($ext === ".gif" || $ext === ".jpg" || $ext === ".png" || $ext === ".txt") {
    echo $file."<br>";
}
```

Comment: What about files with no extension? Also files with an extensions shorter or longer than 3? (.py, .c, .conf)

Comment: Why the downvote? He is talking about .txt and image files. So mostly an extension of 3 letters...

Comment: When answering, you have to consider other people might stumble upon this question and try to use the code. He gave an example of two files, never said it's only going to be images and text. But I downvoted for the same reason I commented my code instead of posting it as an answer: it's hacky, inefficient, only applies to certain scenarios and might produce unexpected results.

Comment: I quote: "img with src and some h3 and p html tags with text equal to the .txt file"